# How to detected PC connection from an Android Application?

Tags: android, android-intent, usb, android-service, android-usb

I'm trying to activate USB tethering when i detect a connexion to a linux PC.
I already have found the following intent filter : ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED

Is there a more specific Intent filter to detect data enabled connections ?

If not how can i detect the data connection ?

ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED will do the Job to Deactivate the tethering.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why but checking the charge state seems to do the job. In the following piece of code usbCharge is false when on simple charger and true where on a computer.

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    IntentFilter extraFilterToGetBatteryInfo = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent extraIntentToGetBatteryInfo = context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, extraFilterToGetBatteryInfo);

    int chargePlug = extraIntentToGetBatteryInfo.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;

    if (usbCharge) {
        // Enable tethering
        Intent tetherSettings = new Intent();
        tetherSettings.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
        tetherSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(tetherSettings);
    }
}
```